# How to Set ViewBag Properties for _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to pass a ViewBag property to customize html in _Layout.cshtml.

```
@Styles.Render(ViewBag.IsEnglish ? "~/Content/css-en" : "~/Content/css-ur")
```

To do this, I have code in my base controller

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewBag.IsEnglish = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("Culture") ?
            (Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString().ToLower() == "en")
            : true;
    }
}
```

But my _Layout.cshtml gives error where ViewBag is called, before the controller's code setting that property is ever reached. I thought _Layout is executed by the ViewEngine, and ViewEngine runs after Controllers have run. Where should I place my ViewBag initialization code so that it becomes available to _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: Why don't you just simply check the culture in your `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: Yes. That would be good to do. But in order to do that (check the culture in _layout.cshtml), I need to put some logic in a "code behind" file for this cshtml. It is not good practice to put in logic inside a cshtml file directly. So which file should this logic go in? This is what I was trying to do by putting it in a basecontroller.

Comment: In principle, no, logic should not exist in views. However, the logic in question is about displaying and not about data manipulation. I mean, you just check the culture of your application... Even if it were, it's still negligible in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your base controller, try this:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    ViewBag.IsEnglish = requestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("Culture") ?
        (requestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString().ToLower() == "en") : true;

}
```

I assume you want to default to English. If that's not the case, change `: true;` to `: false;`

See also [Controller.Initialize method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score -2):

try using the Viewbag on your Action that returns the View that uses _Layout.cshtml